# Can I use ::selection Selector in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-design

I wanted to know if there is some way we can use `::selection` in Material-UI.
Code :-

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Inbox';

const styles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
        },
        '&:selection': {
            backgroundColor: 'tomato',
        },
    },
}));

const Items: React.FC = () => {
    const classes = styles();
    return (
        <List component='nav' aria-label='management side bar'>
            <div className={classes.root}>
                <ListItem button>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                        <InboxIcon />
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary='Inbox' />
                </ListItem>
            </div>
        </List>
    );
};

export default Items;
```

I just want to change the color of the background on selecting the `List Component`, can I do that using the simple '::selection' selector in material-ui?

Answer (score 1):

In your example you are using the `hover` **[pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)** and the `selection` **[pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)**

All pseudo-classes are used via `:` and pseudo-elements via `::`

Therefore, your styled code should look like this:

```js
const styles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    root: {
        '&:hover': {
            backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.contrastText,
        },
        '&::selection': {
            backgroundColor: 'tomato',
        },
    },
}));
```